# unique id without auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing schema with a non-auto-incrementing primary key. The key is used as a foreign key in a dozen other tables.

I have inherited a program with major performance problems. Currently, when a new row is added to this table, this is how a new unique id is created:

```
1) a query for all existing primary key values is retrieved
2) a random number is generated
3) if the number does not exist in the retrieved values, use it, otherwise goto (2)
```

The app is multi-threaded and multi-server, so simply grabbing the existing ids once at startup isn't an option. I do not have unique information from the initiating request to grab and convert into a pseudo-unique value (like a member id).

I understand it is theoretically possible to perform surgery on the internals to add autoincrementing to an existing primary key. I understand it would also be possible to systematically drop all foreign keys pointing to this table, then create-rename-insert a new version of the table, then add back foreign keys, but this table format is dictated by a third-party app and if I mess this up then Bad Things happen.

Is there a way to leverage sql/mysql to come up with unique row values?

The closest I have come up with is choosing a number randomly from a large space and hoping it is unique in the database, then retrying when the odd collision occurs.

Ideas?

Comment: Is a guid via [MySQL's UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) viable, or must it be numeric?

Comment: What is the data type of the existing column?  Assuming it's an `int`, no need to drop the existing keys, just alter the table and make the field an `auto_increment`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df7c1/1

Comment: You can get the highest number used so far, make the column auto increment from next number.

Comment: The column is the primary key, and it is used as a reference for foreign keys. It appears I am unable to simply modify it without receiving errors, such as "Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint"

Comment: What's the data type on this primary key column?

Answer (score 2):

If the table has a primary key that isn't being used for foreign key references, then drop that primary key.  The goal is to make your column an auto-incremented primary key.

So, look for the maximum value and then the following should do what you want:

```
alter table t modify id int not null auto_increment primary key;
alter table t auto_increment = <maximum value> + 1;
```

I don't think it is necessary to explicitly set the auto_increment value, but I like to be sure.

Comment: I can answer that it's not necessary to set the auto_increment value. The auto-increment will not generate a value smaller than MAX(id). You can be sure by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE t` after modifying the id to be an auto-increment.

Comment: Unfortunately the column is the primary key, and is being used for foreign key references (see first sentence of problem description). So I cannot alter the column without receiving errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can SELECT MAX('strange-id-column')+1. That value will be unique and you can put that sql code inside a transaction with the INSERT code in order to prevent errors.

Comment: Not a good idea, because it's subject to race conditions. Two separate transactions could both try to generate the same new id value.

Comment: I concur with Bill Karwin. It's true you could do a `SELECT(MAX(id)+1`... but the idea that the value returned is going to be **unique**, that isn't true. (At least, not in a multi-threaded environment, without adding some concurrency killing locks.)

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I mean transaction and locking. But I think this SQL answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really expensive to pull back a list of all primary key values (for large sets), and then to generate psuedo-random value and verify it's unique, by checking it against the list.

One of the big problems I see with this approach is that a pseudo-random number generator will generate the *same* sequence of values, when the sequence is started with the same seed value.

If that ever happens, then there will be collision after collision after collision until the sequence reaches a value that hasn't yet been used. And the next time it happens, you'd spin through that whole list again, to add one more value.

I don't understand why the value has to be random.

---

If there's *not* a requirement for pseudo-randomness, and an ascending value would be okay, here's what I would do if I didn't want to make any changes to the existing table:

I'd create another "id-generator" table that has an auto_increment column. I perform inserts to that table to generate id values.

Instead of running a query to pull back all existing `id` values from the existing table, I'd instead perform an INSERT into the "id-generator" table, and then a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the `id` of the row I just inserted, and that would use that as "generated" `id` value.

Basically, emulating an Oracle SEQUENCE object. It wouldn't be necessary to keep *all* of the rows in "id-generator" table. So, I could perform a DELETE of all rows that have an `id` value less than the maximum `id` value.

---

If there *is* a requirement for pseudo-randomness (*shudder*) I'd probably just attempt the INSERT as a way to find out if the key exists or not.  If the insert fails due to a duplicate key, I'd try again with a different `id` value.

The repeated sequence from a pseudo-random generator scares me... if I got several collisions in a row... are these from a previously used sequence, or are they values from a different sequence. I don't have any way of knowing. Abandoning the sequence and restarting with a new seed, if that seed has been used before, I'm off chasing another series of previously generated values.

Comment: I agree it is expensive - ridiculously so. I am working on one problem at a time, but the same thing is being done in other tables but with varchar keys! Yuck. The values do not have to be random - that was just one thought - sort of a poor man's hashing function. The id-generator table is interesting and looks like it could work as long as it is in a transaction.

Comment: @Matt: I meant to mention that, regarding transactions. That step of getting and `id` wouldn't necessarily need to be in the context of a transaction. So, a MyISAM table would work.

Comment: @MattThompson: Modifying the column in the existing table to be AUTO_INCREMENT is another option... I didn't recommend that because that change (while it seems simpler) would actually require more investigation and more changes to the application... I suspect that the "generate id" procedure was implemented (in part) as a solution to the "I don't know the id of the row I just inserted" problem. Replacing the "generate unique id" function is actually a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

For low levels of concurrency (average concurrent ongoing inserts < 1) You can use optimistic locking to achieve a unique id without autoincrement:

1. set up a one-row table for this function, eg:

`create table last_id (last_id bigint not null default 0);`

2. To get your next id, retrieve this value in your app code, apply your newId function, and then attempt to update the value, eg:

```
select last_id from last_id; // In DB
newId = lastId + 1 // In app code
update last_id set last_id=$newId where last_id=$lastId // In DB
```

Check the number of rows that were updated.  If it was 0, another server beat you to it and you should return to step 1.